# Weak' must not be applied to non-class-bound consider adding a protocol conformance that has a class bound

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have a made a protocol in my VC in which i'm getting the location placemark from one my my swift file class. In my swift class i have declare the protocol like this,

```
 weak var delegate: HandleMapSearch?
```

But the xcode is showing me error `'weak' must not be applied to non-class-bound 'HandleMapSearch'; consider adding a protocol conformance that has a class bound` . It was working fine before but now when i run the app it shows this error. What is this for and how can i remove this error? This is how i have created protocol in my VC class.

```
protocol HandleMapSearch {
func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark)
}
```

Comment: I have searched this but i couldn't get the answer. @Martin R

Comment: `protocol HandleMapSearch: class { ... }`

Comment: i didn't get what u have written can u plz elaborate? @MartinR

Comment: **protocol HandleMapSearch : class {
    func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark)
}**

Comment: still it is showing same error. @Sh_Khan

Comment: In this line protocol HandleMapSearch : class  where class is written i have to replace it with my VC class name? @Sh_Khan

Comment: no , copy it as it is

Comment: i have written that but my error remains the same. @Sh_Khan

Comment: ok edit your code

Comment: @ raheem: Conform your protocol with class, because we need weak to break the strong reference cycle and it happens only with class.

Comment: protocol HandleMapSearch: AnyObject

Comment: @MartinR, this is not a duplicate.  It is a separate error message.

Comment: Add `: class` after `protocol HandleMapSearch` and before { .  @MartinR could have been a little more helpful in his comment by instead posting an answer and not have closed this as a duplicate.  This is a commonly encountered problem.  The fix should look like this: `protocol HandleMapSearch: class {`.

Comment: As @MohamedAzizBessrour mentioned, use `protocol HandleMapSearch: AnyObject { ... }` if you use Swift 4 or later. https://useyourloaf.com/blog/class-only-protocols-in-swift-4/

Comment: You need to conform AnyObject in your protocol like this:

   `protocol HandleMapSearch: AnyObject {
        func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark)
    }`

as @MohamedAzizBessrour mentioned.

The reason is that by conforming AnyObject, you are making sure that the delegate that adopts this AnyObject, must be a class. As a result, you may now declare your delegate variable as weak.